# (PHP) trying to manipulate include function

Tags: php

I am using the include function to generate the sidenav.php page into my other website pages.
this is the sidenav.php :

```
        <div class="sidenav">      
        <h3> HTML Collection</h3> 
        <a class="current" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href ='html_default.php';"> HTML Intro</a>  
        <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = 'html_editors.php';"> HTML Editors</a>  
    </div>
```

---

now as you can see I am using class: current method to highlight the page I am in.
the problem is since I am using include to  generate that page, it will always highlight the first line of the side nav for every page even if I am not in the intro page
can you please help me to manipulate this?
I have been trying for 2 days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check on what page you are right now with [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Try this quick & dirty solution:

```
<?php
   $class1 = '';
   $class2 = '';
   $class3 = '';

   $prefix = '/html/html_';

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $prefix.'default.php') {
       $class1 = 'current';
   } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $prefix.'editors.php') {
       $class2 = 'current';
   } else {
       $class3 = 'current';
   }
?>

<div class="sidenav">      
<h3> HTML Collection</h3> 
    <a class="<?= $class1 ?>" href="html_default.php">HTML Intro</a>  
    <a class="<?= $class2 ?>" href="html_editors.php">HTML Editors</a>  
    <a class="<?= $class3 ?>" href="html_basics.php">HTML Basics</a> 
</div>
```

This will compare if the current file path is a match and then will use `current` as a `class`-attribute value.

By the way, you don't need `style="cursor: pointer"` since every browser will show the hand icon when you have an `<a>` tag. Also please use the `href` tag instead of `onclick` to make your life easier and fulfil the W3C validation.

Comment: hello and thank you, do I copy the <php ?> u provided into the include file or to the many pages that use the include? also does onlcik harm my seo? cuz I don't mind it

Comment: You have posted your example code in your question. You can replace everything with my code. `onclick` provides a quick way to implement javascript into HTML but is considered a bad practise, so it would harm your SEO. You should use `href` every time you use the `<a>` tag (anchor tag).

Comment: hey I tested this, I copied, it didn't work, I tried to play with it then it highlight both

Comment: On what page did you try it? What is the full browser address?

Comment: Okay, you didn't mentioned that there are three links. I have updated my answer. Try the updated code please. If you find my answer helpful please upvote or accept it.

Comment: it not working u check just the page, still highlight 1

Comment: Hmm, can you add a `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` after the `<?php` ?

Comment: i did  like this    <?php var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $class1 = '';     not work yet

Comment: added what u said, cant use space here

Comment: Thanks, it helped me debugging the issue. Try my updated code again please.

Comment: Haha, glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to just use unique id's on each page, and use the ids to target your link and add the appropriate style.

```
<body id='page_about'>
    <a id='nav_about' href='about.php'>About</a>
    <a id='nav_contact' href='contact.php'>Get in touch</a>
</body>
```

Then CSS something like:

```
#page_about #nav_about,
#page_contact #nav_contact
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

No logic required.

Bear in mind that if you have CSS turned off, the current page link wouldn't get that style.